# flash + xml - the other language of the font

Tags: xml, flash, fonts

it doesn't display the necessary language, English only. after the encoding has been changed, it also doesn't work.probably the font should be changed into a standard one, but i don't know where to do it

Answer (score 1):

You need localized fonts to display localized text correctly. You can set those either directly on the TextField or use the embedFonts property.  Check out this [tutorial](http://www.tutorio.com/tutorial/flash-fonts-complete-tutorial).